# ASUS UX433FN how to have multiple HDMI displays?

Tags: usb, hdmi, display-port

I already have an ASUS UX430 laptop that works perfectly with 2 HDMI displays, which totals 3 displays with the integrated display; this my own personal display.

I needed another laptop and identified the ASUS UX433FN laptop which is about the same as UX430 but a little more "high-end".

I just received the new laptop, an ASUS UX433FN, but it appears it doesn't support 2 HDMI displays like the previous model UX430!! I mean 1 HDMI display is connected on the integrated HDMI plug, and the second display is connected through the USB-C (SuperSpeed+ USB 3.1 Gen 2) plug of the UX433.

I'm very much disappointed by ASUS here, because the very same setup is working with the UX430 (SuperSpeed USB 3.1 Gen 1), but not the UX433.

I'm wondering:

- Is it a temporary lack of software support? Note that I tested with Ubuntu 18.04LTS as well as a daily build pre-version of the future Ubuntu 19.04, and also with MS-Windows 10.
- Is it a hardware limitation of the ASUS UX433 compared to the UX430?

What hardware solution would *you* recommend?

A reseller suggested I buy an additional HDMI graphics card to plug on USB 3.0... What do you think of this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with why this is and what specifically is lacking, but in the official spec sheet, this is a difference between the two.

The [UX430UQ](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX430UQ/Tech-Specs/) lists: ***1 x Type-C™ USB 3.1 Gen 1 with support for external display***
While the [UX433FN](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX433FN/Tech-Specs/) lists: ***1 x USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C™ (up to 10Gbps)***

An external USB Graphics Card (something like [this](https://amzn.to/2C3iM2C)) is certainly a solution that can work, but it may be a bit tricky with Linux support if supported at all.

Comment: In the meantime, someone showed me the same. Thank you! (+1)
Thanks for the important remark about the (maybe missing) Linux support for the USB Graphics Card.

Answer (score 0):

ASUS does not provide display support on the USB-C connector for the UX433 (nor for the UX333). Display support is present for the equivalent 15" model UX533.

The only clue is a small difference in the technical specs.

https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-Zenbook-14-UX433FN/Tech-Specs/

doesn't mention the display:

```
Interfaces    1 x USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C™ (up to 10Gbps)
```

whereas this page:
https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-Zenbook-15-UX533FD/Tech-Specs/

clearly states that it is supported:

```
Interfaces    1 x USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C™ (up to 10Gbps) **with display support**
```

Thanks to Yisroel Tech for the original answer.